# How can I get `UIInput` from a `ui:repeat` in the SiteBean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I am trying to validate multiple components in a `ui:repeat`.

How can I get `UIInput` from a `ui:repeat` in the SiteBean?

JSF code is:

```
    <f:event listener="#{siteBean.listenerMyListener}" type="preValidate" />
    <ez:inputText id="txtMY" required="true" value="Hallo" />

    <ui:repeat
        id ="myRepeat"
        var="item"
        value="#{siteBean.myList}"
        varStatus="status">

        <ez:panel style="margin-bottom: 7px; #{status.even ? 'background-color: #E6EFC2;' : 'background-color: #e5f1fa;'}">

            <h:messages for="hiddenValidation" />
            <h:inputHidden id="hiddenValidation" value="" />

            <h:outputText value="Rechnung vom:" />
            <ez:inputText id="txtDatum" value="#{item.datum}"
                          style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
            </ez:inputText>

            <br /><br />

            <h:outputText value="Netto:" />
            <ez:inputText id="txtNetto" required="true" value="#{item.netto}" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">
                <f:convertNumber pattern="###0.00" />
                <f:validateBean />
            </ez:inputText>

            <br /><br />

            <h:outputText value="Brutto:" />
            <ez:inputText id="txtBrutto" required="true" value="#{item.brutto}" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">
                <f:convertNumber pattern="###0.00" />
            </ez:inputText>

        </ez:panel>

    </ui:repeat>
```

Bean code:

```
public void listenerMyListener(ComponentSystemEvent event) {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    UIComponent components = event.getComponent();


    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();


    UIInput search_txtMY = (UIInput) viewRoot.findComponent("frmMY:txtMY");
    String value_txtMY = search_txtMY.getLocalValue().toString(); // Hallo


    UIInput search_txtDatum = (UIInput) viewRoot.findComponent("frmMY:myRepeat:0:txtDatum"); // NULL
    String value_txtDatum = search_txtDatum.getLocalValue().toString(); // java.lang.NullPointerException  

}
```

Comment: As far as I understand the components within a `<ui:repeat>` are not copied in JSF tree. In other words there is only one `UIInput` object for your 'txtDatum' and it is used to render all the iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `<ui:repeat>` is not a view build time tag, but a view render time tag. There's only one `<h:inputText>` component in the view tree, identified by `frmMY:myRepeat:txtDatum`. It's however rendered multiple times, as many times as the `<ui:repeat>` iterates. If you were using `<c:forEach>`, which is a view build time tag, then there are indeed multiple `<h:inputText>` components in the view, each which are rendered only one time.

You need to solve the problem differently. The `<c:forEach>` might not be the right solution as it may have nasty "side effects", depending on how your entire view and model is designed. As the functional requirement is unclear and the need to collect the input values in a system event listener does not make any sense (I can't think of any sensible real world applicances of this approach), I can't suggest anything how to solve it differently and properly. I *guess* that you just need a `Validator`.

Comment: I try <c:forEach>. I have validators for my inputs. But I can only validate one input each. Is it possible to validate multiple fields here withhin my <ez:panel>? Without multiple forms and tons of submit buttons? I have only two submit button on the top and bottom of my site.

Comment: <c:forEach> do what I need. Thank you :)